# Query MongoDB with $and and Multiple $or

Tags: mongodb, search, operators, expression

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/), this is not possible.

---

## AND Queries With Multiple Expressions Specifying the Same Operator

Consider the following example:

```
db.inventory.find( {
    $and : [
        { $or : [ { price : 0.99 }, { price : 1.99 } ] },
        { $or : [ { sale : true }, { qty : { $lt : 20 } } ] }
    ]
} )
```

This query will return all select all documents where:

the price field value equals 0.99 or 1.99, and
the sale field value is equal to true or the qty field value is less than 20.

***This query cannot be constructed using an implicit AND operation, because it uses the $or operator more than once.***

---

What is a workaround to query something like this? This query returns no results on MongoDB 3.2. I have tested the $or blocks separately and they are working fine, but not when they are wrapped in $and block. I assumed I didn't read the documentation incorrectly that this is not supposed to work. The only alternative I have is to push the data to ElasticSearch and query it there instead, but that's also just a workaround.

```
{
    "$and": [
        {
            "$or": [
                {
                    "title": {
                        "$regex": "^.*html .*$",
                        "$options": "i"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "keywords": {
                        "$regex": "^.*html .*$",
                        "$options": "i"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "$or": [
                {
                    "public": true
                },
                {
                    "domain": "cozybid"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

the documentation doesn't say that this is impossible. It only says

> This query cannot be constructed using an implicit AND operation,
>   because it uses the $or operator more than once.

this means that this will work :

```
db.inventory.find( {
    $and : [
        { $or : [ { price : 0.99 }, { price : 1.99 } ] },
        { $or : [ { sale : true }, { qty : { $lt : 20 } } ] }
    ]
} )
```

but this won't, because it's an **implicit** **`$and`** with two **`$or`**

```
db.inventory.find({
        { $or : [ { price : 0.99 }, { price : 1.99 } ] },
        { $or : [ { sale : true }, { qty : { $lt : 20 } } ] }
})
```

try it online: [mongoplayground.net/p/gL_0gKzGA-u](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gL_0gKzGA-u)

Here is a working case with an implicit **`$and`**:

```
db.inventory.find({ price: { $ne: 1.99, $exists: true } })
```

I guess the problem you're facing is that there is no document matching your request in your collection

Comment: I actually realized after I posted the question that the data has been rolled back on the server by my team. You are absolutely correct. It's the implicit AND that's not supposed to work.

Comment: what if or replaces $and and $and replaced by $or