# Multiple conditions for field in mongoDB with $or

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to retrieve all documents from a MongoDB collection, where `users` field is either numeric or a string, consisting of all digits (1, 2, 19, or "4", "19", ...)

I query:

```
db.getCollection('collection').find(
    { 
        users: { $or : [ { $type: [1, 16, 18, 19] },
                         { $regex: /^[0-9]+$/ } ]
               }
    }
)
```

... and get the error "Unknown operator $or".

This works:

```
db.getCollection('collection').find(
    { 
        $or: [ 
                {users:  { $type: [1, 16, 18, 19] } },
                {users:  { $regex: /^[0-9]+$/ }}
        ]
    }
)
```

Why doesn't the first variant work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$or must itself contains the field upon which you want to query. Your second query contains the field.

```
$or :[{field_name:Match_expression},{field_name:Match_expression}...{field_name:Match_expression}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection('collection').find( {
    $and : [
        { $or : [ { $type: [1, 16, 18, 19] } ] },
        { $or : [ {users:  { $regex: /^[0-9]+$/ } ] }
    ]
} )
```

this should work

**EDIT**

[This is where it was answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40389090/9450101)

Comment: This gives error "unknown top level operator: $type"

Comment: And linked answer describes another problem. Linked answers cites the manuals that say that `$and` can be omitted in certain circumstances ("implicit `$and`"). It looks like similar thing for `$or` is simply not implemented.